# How to import SVGs to QGIS without QGIS changing it?

Tags: qgis, svg

I've been having problems with importing .svg-files to QGIS (LTR 3.10.5). This is how the image looks in Photoshop CC (then exporting as SVG).

[image]

And this is how the SVG translates into QGIS. Basically it loses the lines and the center circle gets black fill.

[image]

Here's the SVG code too.

```
<svg id="Ryhmä_2" data-name="Ryhmä 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="4000" height="2000" viewBox="0 0 4000 2000">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1, .cls-2 {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
      }
      .cls-1 {
        stroke-width: 41.667px;
        fill-rule: evenodd;
      }
      .cls-2 {
        stroke-width: 20.833px;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <path id="Muoto_1" data-name="Muoto 1" class="cls-1" d="M0,1000H1600"/>
  <path id="Muoto_2" data-name="Muoto 2" class="cls-1" d="M2400,1000H4000"/>
  <circle id="Soikio_1" data-name="Soikio 1" class="cls-2" cx="2000" cy="1000" r="400"/>
</svg>
```

How can I fix this problem? I've tried doing the SVG with Inkscape too, but the result in QGIS is the same.

Sorry for the finnish pictures, I hope you can get a hang of the problem!

Comment: Maybe the stroke is too big?

Answer (score 1):

I draw all my SVGs in Inkscape then I paste them in a website such as https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ to remove all the unnecessary text and clean the SVG.

And to have a good control on the looks of my SVG, I add this (for example) using Notepad++ :

```
fill="param(fill) #000000" fill-opacity="param(fill-opacity) 1" stroke="param(outline) #ffffff" stroke-width="param(outline-width) 0.2"
```

So that I can edit colors and stroke in QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why your SVG is not displayed as it should in QGIS but below is an SVG similar to yours that work well in QGIS

```
<svg height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="m50 92.550484v-85.1009644" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="3"/>
<circle cx="50" cy="50" fill="#ffffff" r="16" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="3" transform="matrix(.70710678 -.70710678 .70710678 .70710678 -20.710678 50)"/>
</svg>
```